# Jquery mobile layout advice.

Tags: jquery, mobile

So I have primarily used phonegap to build small iPhone apps. I now have a project that would benefit from jquery mobile.

My question is about the structure of the pages. What makes most sense to me is to split everything into its own page. I.e. profile page, friend page, location page, etc. to take advantage of the animations I would need to keep everything in one HTML page using page containers.

Being new to jquery mobile I am confused as to the benefits of just using one page other than transformations.

Not sure if it matters but all my content is pulled through Ajax calls and JavaScript just replaces content in specified divs.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Keep each functional piece into separate pages. That is the clean and maintainable way to do it. jQuery ajax will automatically load the content (when navigating between pages) via ajax and you will get the [animation](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-links.html), by default. Make sure you follow the the page [anatomy](http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/page-anatomy.html) mentioned by the jQuery mobile documentation (header div, content div, footer div)

Comment: So what your saying is when I click a link and call my jquery to get information from an outside source, then have the page change with JavaScript and replace the div content with the response from the Ajax that I will get the loader and page animations?

Comment: jquery mobile navigation is using ajax load by default.

Comment: Yes I have followed the docs for the $mobile.changepage("my page.html"). What I am not understanding is how to call a external page and then display the response from calling that page in the my page.html.

Comment: Not sure if I mentioned this. Jq mobile is being used in a phonegap app for the iPhone. So when I say external page. It is the external page I call on a web server which accesses my database and returns the information. In straight jquery I would jus do an Ajax call, through the data into a response then replace the div with the response data. So where the. Infusion comes in is that I am wondering if I can do the same with the changepage function so I get the animation for the transition as well as the loading dialogs.